# How to get GPS Coordinates on Google Maps?

Tags: macos, safari, google-maps

Apparently, the feature to right click on a location ("what's here?) and get GPS coordinates for a location while in Google Maps has been changed recently.  Now all I get is street addresses or worse when I right click on a location.   Are GPS coordatines available through Google Maps now?  If not, can we get that feature back?   I'm simply using a laptop that runs MS Explorer---nothing fancy or overly-mobile or exotic.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what it has to do with Apple…

… but the coordinates are in both the info drop-down & the URL

[image]

Comment: When I do that, I only get a street address, or just the county name.  No cooridates anywhere.

Comment: Then you need a different browser. Internet Explorer for Mac was discontinued in 2005.